# Click on a div to make another div appear/disappear

Tags: javascript, css, html, toggle

I'm a bit stuck on trying to make `<div class"portfolio-entry-toggle">` toggle `<div class="portfolio-entry">` to appear and disappear, currently it only works when I hover, but if I click on it - nothing happens. Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/swAP9/

`cheers`

Comment: Are you looking for a pure CSS solution? This is only possible with JavaScript.

Comment: Not really, any solution would do.

Comment: @AlliterativeAlice , not completely true, you have [Stuff you can do with the Checkbox hack here](http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/). Althought that might be overly complicated.

Comment: Are you using jquery? If so, it's just a one-liner: `$(".portfolio-entry-toggle").click(function(){ $(".portfolio-entry").toggle(); });`

Comment: Using jquery:http://jsfiddle.net/swAP9/3/

Answer (score 0):

The only way that you're going to see this work is if you use the :active selector. However, based off of what I am seeing in your JSFiddle, this is not the answer to your question.

As others have mentioned, you could use the jQuery toggle() method. Personally, this is how I would approach this task.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Javascript function like this to toggle the visibility of the portfolio entry. This function will only work in IE > 9, and only in browsers that support querySelector. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector for more info.

Good luck!

```
function toggleEntry() {
    var p = document.querySelector('.portfolio-entry');
    if (p.style.visibility === 'visible') {
        p.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else {
        p.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}

document.querySelector('.portfolio-entry-toggle').
    addEventListener('click', toggleEntry);
```